# How to delete data from DB with the same dates except the biggest date. Rails 3

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have date like:

```
=> #<Item id: 8749, asin: "B000V2ACH8", created_at: "2014-03-24 00:15:24">
=> #<Item id: 8750, asin: "B000V2ACH8", created_at: "2014-03-24 14:35:24">
=> #<Item id: 8751, asin: "B000V2ACH8", created_at: "2014-03-24 19:35:24">
=> #<Item id: 8752, asin: "B000V2ACH8", created_at: "2014-03-24 17:35:24">
...
=> #<Item id: 8753, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-24 21:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8754, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-24 05:24:24">
...
=> #<Item id: 8755, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-23 23:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8756, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-23 22:58:24">
...
=> #<Item id: 8757, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-22 19:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8759, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-22 10:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8760, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-22 23:33:33">
```

How to get max(create_at) of the same year-month-date & delete rest with the same asin & the same year-month-date(lower than max of that date)?
Want to get values like ⬇

```
=> #<Item id: 8751, asin: "B000V2ACH8", created_at: "2014-03-24 19:35:24">
=> #<Item id: 8753, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-24 21:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8755, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-23 23:58:24">
=> #<Item id: 8760, asin: "7770V2A888", created_at: "2014-03-22 23:33:33">
```

Comment: do you want to delete records with asin = 'B000V2ACH8'?

Comment: I have tons of data. I want to delete with the same asin & year-month-date except the biggest date of this asin. Sorry, for my english.

Comment: Sorry once more. I updated the question.

Comment: @emaillenin I updated the question. Probably, I need to group it by year month date too or something like that :)

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the best answer, but it works for me :)
Example :)

```
  @item.try(:each) do |i|
    for j in 0..10
      group_records = Item.where(:asin => i.asin, :domain => i.domain, :user_id => i.user_id).where(:created_at => Date.today.beginning_of_day - j.day..Date.today.end_of_day - j.day)
      max_date = group_records.select('max(created_at) as m').first.m
      group_records.where('created_at != ?', max_date).delete_all
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

`group_records = Item.where('id>0')  # you can put any conditions in`where` clause

```
max_date = group_records.select('max(created_at) as m').first.m
group_records.where('created_at < ?', max_date).delete_all
```

Comment: this would delete all records older than the max date. OP asks to delete for each asin group.

Comment: @whitesiroi did this work for you? I mean did it delete based on asin group>

Comment: @emaillenin yup, I added WHERE, so it was based on asin group. But I still haven't figured one thing out. I updated my question. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @emaillenin, you're right. I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL:

```
DELETE items
FROM items
INNER JOIN (select asin,cast(created_at) created_date, max(created_at) as m
from items group by asin) max_items ON max_items.asin = asin.asin
AND max_items.created_date = cast(items.created_at as DATE)
WHERE items.created_at < max_items.created_at
```

Comment: Thank you for your update.
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: ...from Items INNER JOIN (select asin,cast(created_at) created_...